# scoverage maven plugin does not generate html report

Tags: scala, maven, scoverage

There are some similar questions in the past, but I either don't see any valid answer or in a different situation.
My project is a pure Scala project managed by maven. While the POM file is rather big, I'd only pick some relevant snippets:

```
<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.2</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>compile</goal>
              <goal>testCompile</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
        <configuration>
          <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
          <!--args>
            <arg>-target:jvm-1.8</arg>
          </args-->
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <!-- disable surefire -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <skipTests>true</skipTests>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <!-- enable scalatest -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
        <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.0</version>
        <configuration>
          <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
          <junitxml>.</junitxml>
          <htmlreporters>${project.build.directory}/html/scalatest</htmlreporters>
          <forkMode>once</forkMode>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>scala-test</id>
            <goals>
              <goal>test</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      ......
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.scoverage</groupId>
        <artifactId>scoverage-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.11</version>
        <configuration>
          <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
          <aggregate>true</aggregate>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>report</goal>
            </goals>
            <phase>test</phase>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then I run `mvn clean scoverage:report`, from the log, the instrumented class generated:

```
[INFO] Compiling 259 source files to <I removed project name>/target/scoverage-classes at 1678344142307
```

Unit tests ran:

```
Run completed in 1 second, 130 milliseconds.
Total number of tests run: 8
Suites: completed 3, aborted 0
Tests: succeeded 8, failed 0, canceled 0, ignored 0, pending 0
All tests passed.
```

Then it skipped report generation:

```
[INFO] <<< scoverage:1.4.11:report (default-cli) < [scoverage]test @ spark-pipelines <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- scoverage:1.4.11:report (default-cli) @ spark-pipelines ---
[INFO] Skipping SCoverage report generation
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:13 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-03-09T17:43:22+11:00
```

From target folder, I can see there is only one file source.roots generated in coverage-data folder. There is no site folder generated.

Answer (score 0):

In order to reproduce this issue, I created a very simple Scala project, and the pom file is like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.lhe</groupId>
    <artifactId>coverage-test</artifactId>
    <version>${revision}</version>
    <properties>
        <scala.version>2.12.15</scala.version>
        <scalatest.version>3.0.5</scalatest.version>
        <spark.version>3.2.1</spark.version>
        <delta.version>1.1.0</delta.version>
        <kafka-clients.version>2.0.0</kafka-clients.version>
        <kafka-avro-serializer.version>5.0.1</kafka-avro-serializer.version>
        <kafka-schema-registry.version>5.0.1</kafka-schema-registry.version>
        <spark-cassandra-connector.version>3.0.0-beta</spark-cassandra-connector.version>
        <cassandra-driver.version>3.6.0</cassandra-driver.version>
        <elasticsearch-spark.version>7.15.2</elasticsearch-spark.version>
        <elasticsearch-client.version>7.15.2</elasticsearch-client.version>
        <streaming-avro-schemas.version>5.0.4</streaming-avro-schemas.version>
        <feature-store.version>3.0.191</feature-store.version>
        <log4j.version>2.17.1</log4j.version>
        <revision>development-SNAPSHOT</revision>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.15.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <scalaVersion>${scala.version}</scalaVersion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scoverage</groupId>
                <artifactId>scoverage-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.11</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${project-info-reports.plugin.version}</version>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                            <report>index</report>
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scoverage</groupId>
                <artifactId>scoverage-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${scoverage.plugin.version}</version>
                <reportSets>
                    <reportSet>
                        <reports>
                            <report>report</report> <!-- select only one report from: report, integration-report and report-only reporters -->
                        </reports>
                    </reportSet>
                </reportSets>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
</project>
```

And the mvn output is:

```
% mvn clean scoverage:report
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------------< com.lhe:coverage-test >------------------------
[INFO] Building coverage-test development-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- clean:3.2.0:clean (default-clean) @ coverage-test ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/lhe/Documents/projects/coverage_test/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> scoverage:1.4.11:report (default-cli) > [scoverage]test @ coverage-test >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- scoverage:1.4.11:pre-compile (default-cli) @ coverage-test ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.0:resources (default-resources) @ coverage-test ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/lhe/Documents/projects/coverage_test/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @ coverage-test ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- scala:2.15.2:compile (default) @ coverage-test ---
[INFO] Checking for multiple versions of scala
[WARNING]  Expected all dependencies to require Scala version: 2.12.15
[WARNING]  org.scoverage:scalac-scoverage-runtime_2.12:1.4.11 requires scala version: 2.12.9
[WARNING] Multiple versions of scala libraries detected!
[INFO] includes = [**/*.java,**/*.scala,]
[INFO] excludes = []
[INFO] /Users/lhe/Documents/projects/coverage_test/src/main/scala:-1: info: compiling
[INFO] /Users/lhe/Documents/projects/coverage_test/target/generated-sources/annotations:-1: info: compiling
[INFO] Compiling 1 source files to /Users/lhe/Documents/projects/coverage_test/target/scoverage-classes at 1678352803917
[INFO] prepare-compile in 0 s
[INFO] compile in 3 s
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- scoverage:1.4.11:post-compile (default-cli) @ coverage-test ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ coverage-test ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/lhe/Documents/projects/coverage_test/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:3.10.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ coverage-test ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- scala:2.15.2:testCompile (default) @ coverage-test ---
[INFO] Checking for multiple versions of scala
[WARNING]  Expected all dependencies to require Scala version: 2.12.15
[WARNING]  org.scoverage:scalac-scoverage-runtime_2.12:1.4.11 requires scala version: 2.12.9
[WARNING] Multiple versions of scala libraries detected!
[INFO] includes = [**/*.java,**/*.scala,]
[INFO] excludes = []
[INFO] /Users/lhe/Documents/projects/coverage_test/src/test/scala:-1: info: compiling
[INFO] /Users/lhe/Documents/projects/coverage_test/target/generated-test-sources/test-annotations:-1: info: compiling
[INFO] Compiling 1 source files to /Users/lhe/Documents/projects/coverage_test/target/test-classes at 1678352807660
[INFO] prepare-compile in 0 s
[INFO] compile in 3 s
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- surefire:3.0.0-M8:test (default-test) @ coverage-test ---
[INFO] Using auto detected provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running MainTest
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.07 s - in MainTest
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< scoverage:1.4.11:report (default-cli) < [scoverage]test @ coverage-test <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- scoverage:1.4.11:report (default-cli) @ coverage-test ---
[INFO] Skipping SCoverage report generation
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  11.361 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-03-09T20:06:52+11:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
(base) lhe@LH-EN-WC39DCWGYX coverage_test % mvn clean scoverage:report
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] -----------------------< com.lhe:coverage-test >------------------------
[INFO] Building coverage-test development-SNAPSHOT
[INFO]   from pom.xml
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- clean:3.2.0:clean (default-clean) @ coverage-test ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/lhe/Documents/projects/coverage_test/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> scoverage:1.4.11:report (default-cli) > [scoverage]test @ coverage-test >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- scoverage:1.4.11:pre-compile (default-cli) @ coverage-test ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.0:resources (default-resources) @ coverage-test ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/lhe/Documents/projects/coverage_test/src/main/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:3.10.1:compile (default-compile) @ coverage-test ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- scala:2.15.2:compile (default) @ coverage-test ---
[INFO] Checking for multiple versions of scala
[WARNING]  Expected all dependencies to require Scala version: 2.12.15
[WARNING]  org.scoverage:scalac-scoverage-runtime_2.12:1.4.11 requires scala version: 2.12.9
[WARNING] Multiple versions of scala libraries detected!
[INFO] includes = [**/*.java,**/*.scala,]
[INFO] excludes = []
[INFO] /Users/lhe/Documents/projects/coverage_test/src/main/scala:-1: info: compiling
[INFO] /Users/lhe/Documents/projects/coverage_test/target/generated-sources/annotations:-1: info: compiling
[INFO] Compiling 1 source files to /Users/lhe/Documents/projects/coverage_test/target/scoverage-classes at 1678352966783
[INFO] prepare-compile in 0 s
[INFO] compile in 3 s
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- scoverage:1.4.11:post-compile (default-cli) @ coverage-test ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- resources:3.3.0:testResources (default-testResources) @ coverage-test ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/lhe/Documents/projects/coverage_test/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- compiler:3.10.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ coverage-test ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- scala:2.15.2:testCompile (default) @ coverage-test ---
[INFO] Checking for multiple versions of scala
[WARNING]  Expected all dependencies to require Scala version: 2.12.15
[WARNING]  org.scoverage:scalac-scoverage-runtime_2.12:1.4.11 requires scala version: 2.12.9
[WARNING] Multiple versions of scala libraries detected!
[INFO] includes = [**/*.java,**/*.scala,]
[INFO] excludes = []
[INFO] /Users/lhe/Documents/projects/coverage_test/src/test/scala:-1: info: compiling
[INFO] /Users/lhe/Documents/projects/coverage_test/target/generated-test-sources/test-annotations:-1: info: compiling
[INFO] Compiling 1 source files to /Users/lhe/Documents/projects/coverage_test/target/test-classes at 1678352970394
[INFO] prepare-compile in 0 s
[INFO] compile in 3 s
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- surefire:3.0.0-M8:test (default-test) @ coverage-test ---
[INFO] Using auto detected provider org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4Provider
[INFO] 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]  T E S T S
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Running MainTest
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.079 s - in MainTest
[INFO] 
[INFO] Results:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< scoverage:1.4.11:report (default-cli) < [scoverage]test @ coverage-test <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- scoverage:1.4.11:report (default-cli) @ coverage-test ---
[INFO] Skipping SCoverage report generation
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  11.453 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-03-09T20:09:35+11:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: did you manage to fix it?

Comment: @hey_rey no i gave up and went for a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

The README [specifies](https://github.com/scoverage/scoverage-maven-plugin#prerequisities--limitations) that only two plugins are supported

```
Plugin is compatible with two Maven Scala compiler plugins:
  SBT Compiler Maven Plugin - version 1.0.0-beta5 or later required,
  Scala Maven Plugin - version 3.0.0 or later required, addScalacArgs and analysisCacheFile configuration parameters cannot be set directly, use project properties 'addScalacArgs' and 'analysisCacheFile' instead.
```

`maven-scala-plugin` is not in the list.